# Is there a way to normalize unicode characters in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode

Is there a way in dart/flutter that can convert any fancy unicode text back to its regular counterpart?

for example:

Input:  ℚ Ｂｒｏｗｎ   ⓞⓥⓔⓡ ʇɥǝ

Output: The Quick Brown Fox Jumped over the Lazy Dog

Thank you!

reference: https://onlinetools.com/unicode/normalize-unicode-text

Comment: Either https://pub.dev/documentation/unorm_dart/latest/unorm_dart/nfkc.html or use javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize